# Is this string to list conversion feasible for 10^5 charcter string?

Tags: python, algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

I'm solving a programming challenge with data structures that I need to transform a string into a queue ADT (I'm using deque from collections). So I came up with this code `text = deque([x for x in text])`. This string can be up to 100.000 characters long. Can time complexity of this conversion be feasible to this size of string? I imagine that it is O(N).

Comment: Yes but the list comprehension is unnecessary. Give the string directly to "deque".

Comment: You can't do better than O(n), since it has to copy every character of the input string into the deque.